# Merge/Join pandas dataframe with condition

Tags: python, pandas

I have a two pandas DataFrame `df1` and `df2`. The relationship between them is one-to-many, and in some instances it can be one-to-one. When the relationship is one-to-many, I'd like to join columns with certain conditions. I'll illustrate with some data.

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({
                    'vid': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
                    'lid': [6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
                    'v': [3, 5, 6, 1, 9]
                  })

df2 = pd.DataFrame({
                    'lid': [6, 6, 8, 8, 10],
                    'av': ['$10','$5','$4','$3','$2'],
                    'cr': [0.04, 0.05, 0.03, 0.04, 0.01]
                  })
```

For rows where there are multiple joins in `df2` i.e `lid` `6` and `8`, I'd like to apply some function say, get the `max` of `av` and `cr`.

Expected output:

```
vid lid  v  av      cr
1    6   3  $10     0.05
2    7   5  np.nan  np.nan
3    8   6  $5      0.04
4    9   1  np.nan  np.nan
5    10  9  $2      0.01
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For match by max or by min by both columns create helper column `tmp` and join new DataFrame created by sorting per columns `lid` and `tmp` with remove duplicates per `lid`:

```
df2['tmp'] = list(zip(df2['av'].str.strip('$').astype(int), df2['cr']))

#sorting by ascending and desceding for match by maximal of tuple in col tmp
df = (df1.merge(df2.sort_values(['lid','tmp'], ascending=[True, False])
                   .drop_duplicates('lid'), how='left', on='lid')
                   .drop('tmp', axis=1))
print (df)
   vid  lid  v   av    cr
0    1    6  3  $10  0.04
1    2    7  5  NaN   NaN
2    3    8  6   $4  0.03
3    4    9  1  NaN   NaN
4    5   10  9   $2  0.01
```

---

```
df2['tmp'] = list(zip(df2['av'].str.strip('$').astype(int), df2['cr']))

#sorting both ascending for match by minimal of tuple in col tmp
df = (df1.merge(df2.sort_values(['lid','tmp'])
                   .drop_duplicates('lid'), how='left', on='lid')
                   .drop('tmp', axis=1))
print (df)
   vid  lid  v   av    cr
0    1    6  3   $5  0.05
1    2    7  5  NaN   NaN
2    3    8  6   $3  0.04
3    4    9  1  NaN   NaN
4    5   10  9   $2  0.01
```

EDIT: If aggregate `max` or `mean` aggregation working for each column separately, so ouput is different like solutions above:

```
df2['tmp'] = df2['av'].str.strip('$').astype(int)

df = df1.merge(df2.groupby('lid').max(), how='left', on='lid')
print (df)
   vid  lid  v   av    cr   tmp
0    1    6  3   $5  0.05  10.0
1    2    7  5  NaN   NaN   NaN
2    3    8  6   $4  0.04   4.0
3    4    9  1  NaN   NaN   NaN
4    5   10  9   $2  0.01   2.0

df = df1.merge(df2.groupby('lid').mean(), how='left', on='lid')
print (df)
   vid  lid  v     cr  tmp
0    1    6  3  0.045  7.5
1    2    7  5    NaN  NaN
2    3    8  6  0.035  3.5
3    4    9  1    NaN  NaN
4    5   10  9  0.010  2.0
```

Comment: while this the expected output, I am looking for a solution where I can apply different functions `max`, `min`, `mean` etc. Can you suggest a more flexible solution?

Comment: @kms - `, I am looking for a solution where I can apply different functions max, min, mean` - can you be more specific? How looks expected ouput if use `mean` ? Answer was edited, but not sure if it is what need.

Comment: @jezrael are you on SO 24*7, what about your office?

Comment: @HimanshuPoddar - From 7:00 to 16:00 onl in working days in my work